# Why when I load google maps, it does not display the location I want

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

When I load my google map navigation with specific coords, the map  does not center the display to the location I have set. Why does it do this? and how do I go about fixing it?

My Script Code: This is a fully functional webpage, however when you place the google map within the accordion for some reason the location of the map does not work.

```
<!doctype html> 
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <title>London Tour Guide</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <script src="jquery.js"></script>

    <style>
        div.container { position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 400px; width: 720px; height: 1300px;
            background-color: white; }

        div.content {
            width: 700px; height: 1200px;
            background-color: lightblue; padding: 5px; }

        h1.welcome {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; color: orangered;
            text-align: center; text-shadow: 2px 2px Grey;
            transition: 4s;}

        h1.stpauls{font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; color: orangered;
            text-align: center;
        }

        h1.welcome:hover{transform: rotateX(360deg); color:yellow; }

        p.medium {
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
    color: #333;
        }

        p.small {
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
    color: #333;
        }

        img {
            display: block;
            margin: auto;
        }


        ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: #333;
        }

        li {
            float: left;
        }

        li a, .dropbtn {
            display: inline-block;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
            background-color: red;
        }

        li.dropdown {
            display: inline-block;

        }

        .dropdown-content {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #f9f9f9;
            min-width: 160px;
            box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        }

        .dropdown-content a {
            color: black;
            padding: 12px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
            text-align: left;

        }

        .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

        .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
            display: block;
        }


        .dropbtn1 {
            background-color: #4CAF50;
            color: white;
            padding: 16px;
            font-size: 16px;
            border: none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }


        .dropbtn1:hover, .dropbtn1:focus {
            background-color: #3e8e41;
        }


        .dropdown1 {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
        }


        .dropdown1-content {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #f9f9f9;
            min-width: 160px;
            box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        }


        .dropdown1-content a {
            color: black;
            padding: 12px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
        }


        .dropdown1-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

        .show{display:block;}

        button.accordion {
            background-color: #eee;
            color: #444;
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 18px;
            width: 100%;
            border: none;
            text-align: left;
            outline: none;
            font-size: 15px;
            transition: 0.4s;
        }

        button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
            background-color: #ddd;
        }

        div.panel {
            padding: 0 18px;
            display: none;
            background-color: white;
        }

        div.panel.show {
            display: block;
        }




    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<div class = "content">

    <div class = "header">
        <img src = "headerlondon.jpg" alt = "header"></div>

    <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="Project.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="Map.html">Maps </a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="travel">Travel <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="Bus.html">Bus</a>
                <a href="Taxi.html">Taxi</a>
                <a href="Tube.html">Tube</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="sightseeing">SightSeeing <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="LondonEye.html">London Eye</a>
                <a href="TowerofLondon.html">Tower of London</a>
                <a href="BigBen.html">Big Ben</a>
                <a href="StPaulsCathedral.html">St Pauls Cathedral</a>
                <a href="BuckinghamPalace.html">Buckingham Palace</a>
                <a href="WestMinister.html">WestMinister</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="Museums">Museums <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="BritishMuseum.html">British Museum</a>
                <a href="ScienceMuseum.html">Science Museum</a>
                <a href="NationalHistoryMuseum.html">National History Museumm</a>

            </div>

        </li>
    </ul>

  <h1 class = "stpauls"> St Pauls Cathedral</h1>





    <button class="accordion">Navigation</button>
    <div class="panel">
        <div id="map" style="left:150px;width:60%;height:300px"></div>

        </div>





</div>

    <script>
        var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
        var i;

        for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
            acc[i].onclick = function(){
                this.classList.toggle("active");
                this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
            }
        }
    </script>

    <script>
        var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
        var i;

        for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
            acc[i].onclick = function() {
                this.classList.toggle("active");
                this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
                google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
            }
        }

        function myMap() {
            var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
            var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742, -0.120850);
            var mapOptions = {
                center: myCenter,
                zoom: 10
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myCenter
            });
            marker.setMap(map);
            setTimeout(function () {
                console.log(1);
                google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
            }, 1000);
        }

        </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB37us778WYnwNjHftUm3oL2oduV_WOt_E&callback=myMap"></script>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The var `myCenter` isn't affected to the showing map

Comment: I've suggested an edit to make this question easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should load google map api script before your function.

Comment: No because you are trying to load the map api before you have even carried out the function, so its going to call the api for a non existent call and when the function occurs after it will have no google map to recall

Answer (score 0):

I resolved your issue by adding  `map.panTo(myCenter);` to the onclick function (and moving the declaration of mapCanvas and myCenter to the top:

```
<script>
var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742, -0.12000);

var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
   acc[i].onclick = function(){
      this.classList.toggle("active");
      this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
      //I get a grey block where the map should be unless I add resize here
      google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
      //comment out this line to recreate your issue
      map.panTo(myCenter);
   }
}

var mapOptions = {
     center: myCenter,
     zoom: 16
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myCenter,
});
marker.setMap(map);
setTimeout(function () {
    console.log(1);
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
}, 1000);
</script>
```

Look at jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fqt7L/720/)
Click on the Navigation button to display the map.

Comment: So it has something to do with the marker then? If so what would be wrong with it

Comment: No, it all seems to work in jsfiddle...look http://jsfiddle.net/fqt7L/657/

Comment: Yeah sorry, the problem i dont think is with the Google map but in fact with my actual page. Ill place it in the question and then youll see my issue.

Comment: Try moving your Script below the last </div> and see if that has any effect

Comment: is your map just displaying as a grey block?

Comment: You may need to set the center of the map after triggering the resize event.

Comment: The map is not displaying grey, it displays it fine it just displays it a little off from where my marker is so you cant see it!

Comment: Since I have already cantered why do I need to do it again? If that is the case how would I go about doing it?

Comment: I'd edited by answer to provide a resolution. In this post they talk about the need to resize if the div is hidden, because if it is hidden, it will have zero size and you will need to display the div before it will have a valid size. They also say you need to you  need to set the center of the map after triggering the resize event, which I've done above.

Comment: When i try insert into my code, it does not work. The panel does not open for some reason, any reason for this?

Comment: its difficult for me to say without seeing what you've done.

Comment: Don't use my full script- just put ```map.panTo(myCenter);``` in your ```acc[i].onclick = function``` You'll need to be sure the ```mapCanvas``` and ```myCenter``` are accessible there. You seems to have ```acc[i].onclick = function``` defined twice and I don't understand why.

Comment: Because one does the showing off the panel and the content inside where as the other allows the map to refresh inside the panel otherwise it doesn't work it turns grey.  Should I remove one and replace it with just one full version because I doubt that will work

Comment: I've essentially just added the map.panto my second acc because that's the one which displays the map, I tried your method and it doesn't work because for some reason in the console it says google doesn't exist for some reason I can provide an example if you like

Comment: See how I moved the declaration of the mapCanvas and mapCenter to the top of the script? Did you do that as well?

Comment: If you provide an example I'll have a look